# Как действуют volumes в docker?

Tags: docker

Есть такая команда:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from myredis -v $(pwd)/backup:/backup2 debian cp /data/dump.rdb /backup2/
```

`myredis` - Это контейнер, запущенный в фоновом режиме.

`$(pwd)/backup` - это моя папка на моём компьютере без докера, правильно?
Она будет общей с папкой `/backup2` в контейнере `myredis`.

А далее мы выполняем команду копирования файла в папку `backup2`, но команда-то эта выполняться будет в новом контейнере `debian`, откуда там возьмётся папка `/data` и папка `/backup2/`?

Answer (score 2):

Демон докера при запуске нового контейнера

- возьмёт все volumes из `myredis` и примонтирует внутрь как они были указаны при запуске `myredis`
- примонтирует папку `$(pwd)/backup` внутрь как `/backup2`

Так что `/data` появится только если она есть в `myredis`.